# How to conform image to match border-radius of a div?

Tags: css, image

So I have the following css code:

```
.crop img{
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
    /* width:100%; */
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    object-fit:cover;
    object-position: center;
}
```

What this code does is it takes an image from a URL, places it inside a div that I have, fills the div, then moves up 50%, so that the middle half of the image is displayed in my div. The problem here is that the div my image is in has rounded corners in the top left and right, but by moving the image up 50%, I can't confirm the image to fit the rounded corners (see image below).

[image: example of my problem]

Is there anything I can do to make the image fit into the rounded corners of the div, without declaring them manually? Is there like an `inherit` tag or anything I can use? Sadly I can't provide a working example of my problem, as it is locked behind a login page.

Comment: Add overflow: hidden in the parent div which has rounded corners

Comment: yep, this worked! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `{overflow: hidden}` to your `div`.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is interested, the answer is courtesy of @wilkoklak, who says to use `overflow:hidden;` in the parent div with the rounded corners. Thanks, wilkoklak!